# How to make Liferays VelocityVariables accessable for Intellisense in IntelliJ 12

Tags: intellij-idea, liferay, liferay-velocity

i've our Liferay web content templates (.vm) in a IntelliJ-12 project and want to make the VelocityVariables accessable in the Editor, so some code like this:

```
#set ($portalURL = $getterUtil.getString($request.attributes.CURRENT_COMPLETE_URL))
```

knows about $getterUtil, $request and it's methods from all those [VelocityVariables](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs-all/src-html/com/liferay/portal/velocity/VelocityVariablesImpl.html)

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define Velocity variables in comments, e.g.

```
#* @vtlvariable name="getterUtil" type="GetterUtil" *#
```

You can also do this in a special file so that your source code is not polluted with such comments.

To make IDEA aid you in this, put your caret on a usage of a variable in a Velocity template and press Alt+Enter to invoke quick-fix list. Then select "Define variable in comment" action.

Comment: "Define variable in comment" is great!